# Como verificar se um JInternalFrame já está aberto no JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, jdesktoppane, jinternalframe

Como verificar se um `JInternalFrame` já está aberto no `JDesktopPane` e, caso esteja, colocar ele em foco sobre os outros? Já tentei de várias formas que encontrei pesquisando, mas sempre abre um novo frame, mesmo que o mesmo já esteja aberto.

Esse é o código executado ao clicar no item correspondente no JMenu:

```
private void jMenuItemRegisterEmployeeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          
    RegisterEmployeeJInternalFrame register = new RegisterEmployeeJInternalFrame();
    jDesktopPaneMain.add(register);
    register.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua classe principal(a do Frame que acomoda o `JDesktopPane`), crie uma variável na nesta classe relativa ao frame interno:

```
private RegisterEmployeeJInternalFrame register;
[...]
```

Quando a opção do menu for selecionada, cheque se esse frame está visível, se não estiver, apenas o torne visível e readicione no `JDesktopPane`, pois se seu `JInternalFrame` for "closable"(pode ser fechado), ele é removido do desktoppane quando fechado.

```
private void jMenuItemRegisterEmployeeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                          

    if(register == null ){
        register = new RegisterEmployeeJInternalFrame();
    }

    if(!register.isVisible()){
        dtp.add(register);
        register.setVisible(true);
    }

    register.toFront();
}
```

Dessa forma, se a tela ainda nem foi instanciada e aberta, ela vai ser criada, e se já foi instanciada e foi fechada, ela vai ser reaberta e lançada a frente de outros frames internos, graças ao `toFront()`.

Comment: Funcionou! Perfeito! Muito obrigado, Diego!

Comment: @Lucas disponha! :)